# Local portable grunt distribution?

Tags: html, node.js, gruntjs

I am currently creating a portable consolidation of my workflow using Node-Webkit which has node.js embedded. Now my problem is getting grunt/gulp inside the project itself as it depends on the cli somewhat(avoidable, granted), and also is confusing to me on the architecture. Is it possible to find just a .js with grunt in it to include much like Jquery/Handlebars?

[Is this all I need to just include and run?](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt.js)

Comment: `grunt-cli` is the only thing that won't be easily portable as you'll have to add it to the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No before that make sure you environment is up, get the **package.json, GruntFile.js** file. In **GruntFile.js**  you can specify what you want to pre-process. For example **jade,Less,coffee**. It looks very much like a node function, for sample you can refer to [link](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile)

Now to make this work you also need to install various **contrib plugins** as per your requirement. Then register every single task in **GruntFile.js**. It really speeds up the development.

```
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jade');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-coffee');
  grunt.registerTask('test', ['jade', 'less','coffee']);
```

So to process **less,jade,coffee**, we need to run the module installations such as

```
npm install grunt --save-dev    
npm install grunt <module name> --save-dev
```

There are many more interesting configurations to learn and documentation is really nice, please refer to [getting started guide](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started)
This adds the required Grunt and grunt plugins to **package.json**